# Using node-fetch to retrieve data from a specified site

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my first bot for Discord and I want it to do something that comes with some apparent complications.

I want to query a website when the bot is given a command then retrieve data by class name, then interpret the node for output. 
I believe I can do this using a combination of node-fetch, this code:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("h4.db-item__list__name, p.db-item__list__material");
```

and then an array interpretation. for ease, this is the webpage I'm testing on:

https://eu.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/playguide/db/recipe/2c299ec29ce/

Example: node-fetch connects to the webpage, finds the materials required to make this item, prints the materials in a node which is then interpreted as an array, then I can use a line to echo this into the console.

Is this a possibility, or am I creating a big headache for myself that in the long run only works 10% of the time (been there before). Also am I in the right ball park already if this is possible? I'm not looking for someone to code this for me, I just want to make sure I'm not going to waste hours on this before I get too deep.

Comment: Look into PhantomJS

Comment: Thanks! I just had a quick look and I think I get the idea - is it a "phantom" browser that's invisible to the user, but loads the webpage so that it can be interpreted directly? almost like an invisible iframe?

Comment: It's a non-GUI browser driven by your code. Like its tagline: "scriptable headless browser".

Comment: sounds bang on, thatd make life a ton easier. my only worry is its considered discontinued - problem or nay?

Comment: *shrug* It'll work as well as it ever did. The issues w/ using a non-browser solution is that JS may not be executed, which may or may not be an issue with the site in question. You'd also need to make sure you're not violating the site's TOS.

Comment: Brill that'll do me. thanks guys for the rapid response